# Named virtual host not working in xampp windows

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

I have following config in **extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/history"
    ServerName history.test.in
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/history">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I enabled this in **apache\conf\httpd.conf** file,

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

In **drivers\etc\hosts** file, I have

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.0.1 history.test.in
```

When I try to access http://history.test.in, site is not loading but when tried with http://localhost/history, it works. Am I doing anything wrong? Also, I don't see any error logs in Apache.

Comment: IP based host also works. I mean **http://127.0.0.1/history** is working fine too. The problem is only with named host. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above **configuration** is correct. The reason for the virtual host not working was due to incorrect settings like firewall block, anti-virus software interruption, multiple OS environment etc. in system.

This post(eye-opener) helped me found the issue in windows xampp environment: https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot
especially **ipconfig /displaydns** DNS command helped me find that new hosts take effect correctly.

Additionally, if you are running multiple versions of OS (windows 7, vista or windows 10) in your system, make sure you edit the running **drivers\etc\hosts** OS's hosts file and not the idle one.